# Why could only Logan take Laura to Eden?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In *Logan* (2017), Gabriela tracked down Logan and took his help in sending Laura to Eden, in the process getting killed by the Reavers/henchmen who tracked her down. Of course, she was aware of Laura's DNA connection to Logan, and it makes sense to expect that upon learning about this 'relation', Logan's protective instincts can kick in, and there can be no one better than the mythical *Wolverine* to safeguard Laura's journey to Eden.

It is great storytelling, but thinking about it afterwards, why did she need Logan for this in the first place, considering the following points:

- [An early graveyard scene](https://youtu.be/6wduXeH7-dY?t=2m11s) in the film shows that Gabriela had a light-blue/azul colored car, in which she drove past Logan, with Laura in the backseat. So, *she had a car* already.
- She offered Logan (*plenty of*) money to get this job done. So, *she had ample amount of money* too. So, even if she didn't have a car herself, she could've easily hired one for this long-distance journey.
- She knew the location/co-ordinates of the place they were heading to, and most importantly, **the Reavers did not (initially)**. This is revealed later in the film, after the Munson family disaster, where one of the Reavers retrieves the photograph that Laura carries with her (with co-ordinates at the back). It is only after this that the Reavers start heading full-force towards Eden, beforehand they were only looking locally.
- She knew the Reavers were after them, so there had to be a sense of urgency about the escape. That shouldn't leave any time for convincing *one-particular-driver-out-of-many-in-this-world* for the journey. In fact, this whole find-Logan-convince-Logan scheme would be highly time consuming, for the *Wolverine* is mythically established to be a difficult, stubborn creature. And after all the time expenditure, there is always the possibility of Logan refusing. So, this proposition can also fail.
- She was very well conversant with Laura's adamantium claws and healing powers. So, if we leave out the Reavers/other Transigen henchmen, other mortal humans would not present any threat to her with Laura on her side, and the journey would be absolutely safe.

So, **why couldn't she just take Laura along, either hop onto her car, or use the money to hire any other chauffeur-driven car, dump her phone, quickly escape the local area they started from, and then quietly head towards Eden on her own? The Reavers simply would not have any clue where to look for them.**

Of course, this would completely ruin the emotional narrative *Logan* was intended to be, but isn't this a perfectly logically plausible line of thought? (*Perhaps with this, Logan, Charles Xavier, Caliban, the Munsons, and Gabriela herself would all end up alive.*)

Comment: Hopefully someone can expand on this, but if I remember their idea comes from a comic - they believe Logan knows where it really is.

Comment: @sirjonsnow Pretty much that. In their universe, not only were the X-men real, they were turned into a comic series (just like our universe) and Eden was part of the comic book. Logan rejects the idea of an Eden because he knows most of those stories were just stories.

Comment: @sirjonsnow - That sort of makes sense, but according to [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/69697/52978), those coordinates were possibly planted there as a matter of disguise for escape information, which is also a pretty sensible thing to do. (PS - Sorry for the late response.)

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths - Yes, that sort-of makes sense, but please also see the above comment. Logan's rejection ground is exactly as you mention, but the coordinates were possibly there for a reason. (Sorry for the late response, wasn't on this Stack too often.)

Comment: I think Gabriela doesn't have what it takes to protect Laura. She reaches out to wolverine for two reasons - he's the person with the original gene so the hope is that he will be emotionally involved and try and protect her (which does happen) .. the other is that he's Wolverine, he's capable of keeping Laura alive somehow (and he does). Had she decided to take Laura by herself, she would have just been killed (and she is). Wolverine is all she's got as an option, there are no other mutants left.

Answer (score 2):

Gabriela was hesitant to take her with herself alone as she felt it would be unsafe to carry around a kid who was part of an unstable, illegal and inappropriate experiment conducted by dangerous people who can track the kid(s) and hunt them down. In this case, she could do not much about it. With Laura, she might feel safe, but although she is powerful, she is young and unstable, so that makes her dangerous as well

Logan, on the other hand, is an obvious choice. He is possibly father of one of the kids. He has managed his powers and has control over them.

He is powerful enough to protect them (which he does), and would be a kind of shield between her and them, in case those kids are out of control of her.
Also, the fact helps that Logan is kind of established driver for some time which might be helpful while escaping.

Comment: That's a good perspective. :)